# Creating a table with gray title bar

Tags: tables

I want to create a table as shown below. Can someone provide me an MWE?

[image]

Comment: Load `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and put `\rowcolor{gray!50}` in the beginning of first row. Is that what you want? Please add some code so that we don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Use the package color, colortbl. \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}. \rowcolor{Gray} will produce the color wherever you need.

Comment: @ Harish Kumar: I missed seeing your comment and suggested  almost the same!